# How to pass single touches to underlying views but keep the UIPanGestureRecognizer working?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uigesturerecognizer

I have built a custom index view for my table and collection views, so user can easily scroll through the content. 
However, some cells have the accessory button in them that is placed on right side of the cell. 
If the index view is too wide it blocks the button from receiving the touch.

I don't want the index view to respond to single touches, only swipes so I've used the `UIPanGestureRecognizer` for it and fiddled with `UIGestureRecognizedDelegate` methods to achieve that but I didn't find any solution. I can't set `userInteractionEnabled` on the index view because it would break the pan gesture recognizer.

Is this even possible to achieve this effect?

Comment: I don't think there's a good way to solve that problem, so I went with adjusting the `layoutMargins` of the cell to match the width of index view instead.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your custom index view's subclass :-

```
override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {

    var hitTestView = super.hitTest(point, with: event)
    if (event?.type == UIEvent.EventType.touches) && (hitTestView is Self) {
        hitTestView = nil
    }
    return hitTestView
}
```

hitTest is a very powerful method. It can also be used to determine which view should receive the touch if there are multiple overlapping views or subviews at the same point. This is a pretty good tutorial to know more about this feature (though it is in Objective C) :- [Hit Test iOS](http://smnh.me/hit-testing-in-ios/)

Comment: Unfortunately that passes the touch to the cell's button but the index view does not react to the pan gesture